# Why did Uncle Jesse's last name change?

Tags: continuity, full-house

In season 1 of the show Full House, Uncle Jesse is referred to as "Jesse Cochran" but later in the series he is always Jesse Katsopolis. **So why the name change and is there any in-universe acknowledgment of the change?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

John Stamos' character was originally named Jesse Cochran; Stamos reportedly wanted his character to better reflect his Greek heritage so producers decided to change the character's surname to Katsopolis

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Full_House_characters

In terms of an explanation:
In the first season, Jesse's last name was Cochran, but in the second season it was changed to Katsopolis because of John Stamos' Greek heritage. The reason for the change was addressed within the series in an episode in that the last name "Cochran" was a pseudonym Jesse was using to make his name sound more like a rock star.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092359/trivia

Comment: Interesting, although it doesn't say anything about whether there was an official in-universe explanation for the name change. I guess maybe I'll have to watch the show to find out.